# How to add a select-all chekbox to Column Header in Ag-Grid React?

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

In Ag Grid, there is an option to add a checkbox to a row to select it. This can be defined in columnDefinitions as follows:

```
{
   checkboxSelection: true
}
```

This checkbox is added on the row itself. Now my question is, how to add a select-all checkbox in the column header itself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are almost there. All you have to do is to add `colDef.headerCheckboxSelection=true` as stated in the [docs](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-selection/#header-checkbox-selection)

So it'd be

```js
<AgGridReact
  // needed if you want to select multiple rows. Default is single
  rowSelection="multiple"
  // not required here. Enable this if you only want checkbox selection, and don't want      
  // to also select the row when the row is clicked.
  suppressRowClickSelection
  columnDefs={[{
    field: 'id',
    checkboxSelection: true,
    headerCheckboxSelection: true,},
    ...
  ]}
/>
```

### [Live Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/header-checkbox-selection-uovm3?file=/src/index.js)

Comment: additional question : is there some way to handle events when checkbox on header on/off ( for example based on this checkbox - enable / disable other controls ) ?